# Python - ERROR - failed to write data to stream: <open file '<stdout>', mode 'w' at 0x104c8f150>

Tags: python, django

I'm doing an import data from a CSV file, after entering 210 lines, it returns me this error. I'm doing this from Django shell (manage.py shell)

```
ERROR - failed to write data to stream: <open file '<stdout>', mode 'w' at 0x104c8f150>
```

Comment: You'll need to show what you're executing in the django shell for anyone to stand a chance at working out why you're getting that...

Comment: The error occurred because the sys.stdout.encoding was not the encoding defined there, just do:

import os
import sys

if not sys.stdout.encoding:
     os.putenv ('PYTHONIOENCODING', 'UTF-8')
     os.execv (sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)

Comment: @FernandoA.Valente could you accept answer of lechatpito to makes QA clean

Answer (score 34):

This is a problem with the IPython encoding that is not UTF-8. `export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8` will solve it.

Comment: And now a year later I ran into this error message, while simply doing something like this from the python shell: `SomeModel.objects.all()`. Again this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick.

```
# sys.setdefaultencoding() does not exist, here!
import sys
reload(sys)  # Reload does the trick!
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF-8')
```